# Прошу помощи с Multilanguage

Tags: android, multilanguage

Всем Доброго дня. Очень прошу вашей помощи с созданием Multilanguage в Андроид Студио. То, что нужно было создать в String.xml , я создал. Никак не могу создать или найти код для MainActivity. Всё, что пишу с разных видеоуроков , почему-то даёт ошибку. Очень прошу вашей помощи!

Comment: Что такое Multilanguage?

Comment: чтоб вводить в приложение несколько языков. Например на русском, английском и тд тп.

Answer (score 1):

Тут совсем всё просто.

1. Делаешь файл ресурса строки (по умолчанию язык английский)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Далее на тексте в разметке делаешь Extract Resource
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все. Переход на выбор перевода ctrl + левая кнопка мыши
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переключение языка андроид делает сам. Если нужно только в программе, то нужно смотреть в сторону Locale.
В самом коде обращение такое (пример):

```
text.setText(String.format("%s", getResources().getString(R.string.new_11)));
```

Comment: а что насчёт MainActivity?

Comment: А что там? Я же написал, всё переключается системой автоматически

Comment: Если у вас уже реализованы несколько языков в string.xml и вы хотите, что бы в настройках вашего приложения можно было выбрать язык, отредактируйте вопрос и маякните мне, я вам помогу.

Comment: Здравствуйте Влад. в string.xml добавил языки и с ним вроде всё решено. Не знаю как дать направление с MainActivity к string файлу, чтоб в самом приложении при нажатии кнопки Rus или Eng , язык менял сразу.